# Cosine in floating point

Tags: binary, floating-point, trigonometry

I am trying to implement the cosine and sine functions in floating point (but I have no floating point hardware).

Since my processor has no floating-point hardware, nor instructions, I have already implemented algorithms for floating point multiplication, division, addition, subtraction, and square root.  So those are the tools I have available to me to implement cosine and sine.

I was considering using the CORDIC method, [at this site](http://users-tima.imag.fr/cis/guyot/Cours/Oparithm/english/Sincos.htm)
However, I implemented division and square root using newton's method, so I was hoping to use the most efficient method.

Please don't tell me to just go look in a book or that "paper's exist", no kidding they exist. I am looking for names of well known algorithms that are known to be fast and efficient.

Comment: Can't you find and adapt an existing math library? Because the math below them are quite complex! Writing a competitive math library might worth you a PhD (and would need years of efforts).

Comment: I'm not really a code junkie, I would just like the algorithm and I can do the implementation myself.  I have to rewrite the code in assembly myself and hand schedule it as well.  (It is for a custom processor).

Comment: I believe there are lots of books and papers on that subject. Did you go into a university library?

Comment: Depending on the hardware spec/the precision required, you may find it easier to pre-compute a lookup table than calculate accurately - it depends on your usage case. I believe older scientific calculators used this approach.

Comment: @Basic, I am planning on following Stephen Canon's advice, do you argue that the pre-computed lookup table is faster?  I need precision out to 23 bits (for IEEE-754 floating point).

Comment: Which algorithm will be fastest depends on your hardware. You'll have to try out different ones to see which is the fastest.

Comment: @Gabe, I mean fastest by least number of expensive operations.  For instance, bit shift is preferred over having to divide.

Comment: @starbox I posted that ~2 minutes before Steven's answer - I have no doubt his is a faster solution than mine as I've never had to implement it myself (hence a comment not an answer :)

Comment: @Basic: if you only need limited accuracy and don't care about extremely large inputs (which is often the case), a lookup table is a great approach.  If you want to deliver a fully-accurate floating-point result over the entire range, it's prohibitively expensive in memory usage.

Comment: @StephenCanon Yeah, when OP mentioned 23 bits of precision, it became clear that a lookup table would be huge. That said, you've taught me something with the Argument Reduction... paper - Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, depending on your accuracy requirements, this can be considerably fussier than your earlier questions.

Now that you've been warned: you'll first want to reduce the argument modulo pi/2 (or 2pi, or pi, or pi/4) to get the input into a manageable range.  This is the subtle part.  For a nice discussion of the issues involved, download a copy of K.C. Ng's *ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS: Good to the Last Bit*. (simple google search on the title will get you a pdf).  It's very readable, and does a great job of describing why this is tricky.

After doing that, you only need to approximate the functions on a small range around zero, which is easily done via a polynomial approximation.  A taylor series will work, though it is inefficient.  A truncated chebyshev series is easy to compute and reasonably efficient; computing the minimax approximation is better still.  This is the easy part.

I have implemented sine and cosine exactly as described, entirely in integer, in the past (sorry, no public sources).  Using hand-tuned assembly, results in the neighborhood of 100 cycles are entirely reasonable on "typical" processors.  I don't know what hardware you're dealing with (the performance will mostly be gated on how quickly your hardware can produce the high part of an integer multiply).

Comment: @starbox: minimax approximation is something of a black art.  you only really know about it if you need to use it.  You can start by looking up the "Remez exchange algorithm", which is a standard approach.  A truncated Chebyshev series is much easier to compute, and nearly as good.  A taylor series will require a few more terms to deliver the same accuracy, but is (obviously) very simple.

Comment: @starbox: I should also note that you probably *won't* want to use your existing FP addition and multiplication routines (that's too expensive).  Keeping most of the computation in integer turns out to be easier in some ways, anyway.  The processor that I wrote the integer implementation for actually had an FPU, but I was able to get the result faster without using it.

Comment: @starbox: the reason to avoid using full FP operations is that you don't need to round every step of the computation.  You can carry a little extra precision and delay any rounding logic until the very end.

Comment: When I implemented this code in MATLAB, I am getting large errors from the range reduction, is this to be expected?  As the incoming theta's grow larger and range reduced to between +/- pi/4, the error grows.

Comment: @starbox: a correct range reduction will not introduce large errors no matter how big the input is.  As I noted, however, it is quite difficult to implement a correct range reduction (it's one of the fussiest parts of a floating-point library -- maybe the fussiest).

Comment: I've kept everything to single-precision floating point.  Is that where the issues might be coming in?  I'm not quite sure how to adjust the document you told me to read to pertain to 32-bit floating point.

Comment: @starbox: the exact details of a fully precise range reduction are probably outside the scope of what can be addressed in comments.  If you want to ask a new question, I'll be happy to take a look and see if I can spot the source of your problems, though I won't have a chance to really look at it until the weekend.

Comment: I posted my question.  here is a link to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423516/precision-problems-with-range-reduction

Comment: I was wondering, have you gotten a chance to take a look at my new post regarding range reduction?

Comment: I wonder what *non-contrived* calculations can be performed more accurately by employing argument reduction with a mathematically-perfect Pi than with the nearest double approximation?  Most practical trig calculations I've seen use a double-precision-rounded value for pi or a multiple thereof when computing the arguments to trig functions, and so I would think the optimal accuracy would be achieved by having argument reduction performed on a value of pi that was rounded in the same way as the one used in the argument calculations.  To my mind, the fact that `Math.Sin(Math.Pi)` is non-zero...

Comment: ...should be considered a (tolerable) rounding error, rather than a desirable behavior.  Are there practical cases where assuming a "precise" pi yields a better result than would computing sin(x) as sin(Math.Pi-X) when x is in the range pi/2 to pi?

Answer (score 1):

For various levels of precision, you can find some good approximations here:

http://www.ganssle.com/approx.htm

With the added advantage that they are deterministic in runtime unlike the various "converging series" options which can vary wildly depending on the input value.  This matters if you are doing anything real-time (games, motion control etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Since you have the basic arithmetic operations implemented, you may as well implement sine and cosine using their taylor series expansions.

Comment: I know I could do that, but I want a method that is the most efficient and fastest.  I know some methods use a lookup table, which ones are those and are they much faster?

Comment: what about minimax approximation?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with any minimax algorithms

Comment: See http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00660.pdf for some details on minimax approximations.